# How to implement `upsert` for PostgreSQL in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a stream of data, which contains categories. I want to maintain a Category table which should contain every category I encounter exactly once.

I want to implement a `id = Category.upsert(name)`, which should be atomic (of course), and - if possible - not use stored procedures on the DB side.

Answer (score 1):

[The `upsert` gem seems to do just that](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert) - I found it while googling to see if "upsert" is a thing.

Comment: Looks interesting, but it uses stored procedures, and it doesn't seem to return the id/object (which I need...).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  class << self
    def upsert(name)
      transaction { self.find_or_create_by(name: name).id }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice one, but as far as I understand - it does two round trips to the database... Do you know of a way to do it in one round trip?

Comment: You're right, it does, but as far as I know one can't do any better, not without stored procedures.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to write an ActiveRecordExtension. Check [this](http://codebrahma.com/ruby/2014/08/01/upsert-implementation-in-rails.html) out.

The code will look something like this

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def upsert(attributes)
    begin
        create(attributes)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, PG::UniqueViolation => e
        find_by_primary_key(attributes['primary_key']).
        update(attributes)
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

Comment: This solution is hardly atomic - it doesn't even do two round trips - it does three...